# Get submap with regex

Tags: regex, dictionary, groovy

How can you get the submap of map with a string being a pattern ? Example, I have this map :

```
def map = [val1:ATOPKLPP835, val2: ATOPKLPP847, val3:ATOPKLPP739, val4:YYHSTYSTX439, val5:UUSTETSFEE34]
```

The first three values are identical until the ninth character. I would like to get a submap only with the string "ATOPKLPP". How can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
def map = [val1:'ATOPKLPP835', val2: 'ATOPKLPP847', val3:'ATOPKLPP739', val4:'YYHSTYSTX439', val5:'UUSTETSFEE34']
def found = map.findAll { it.value.startsWith('ATOPKLPP')}

assert found == [val1:'ATOPKLPP835', val2:'ATOPKLPP847', val3:'ATOPKLPP739']
```

You can define whatever criterion in closure passed to `findAll`.